# Nested List in One Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, nested-loops

I am building a professor-lecture-student database that I'm struggling to get the right MySQL queries for.

Here are my tables:

```
Table PROFESSOR (id, name)
Table LECTURE (id, name, professorID, offeredThisYear) ... offeredThisYear is 1 or 0
Table STUDENT (id, name, inState) ... inState = 1 or 0 
Table LECTURE-STUDENT (lectureID, studentID)
```

- Some LECTUREs are offered this year, some or not
- Some STUDENTs are instate, others or not

---

Query I'm trying to write:

For PROFESSOR id = 1, I want a list of all LECTUREs he/she teaches this year (offeredThisYear = 1) and a list of only instate students (inState = 1) registered for the class.  If any LECTURE has no STUDENT, I want it to be still listed.

---

My queries:

```
SELECT * FROM lectures 
WHERE professorid = 2
AND offeredThisYear = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Returns

```
Lecture 15=Law
Lecture 7=Philosophy
Lecture 17=Mathematics
Lecture 13=German
```

Now, for each lecture, I want a list of instate students like:

```
Lecture 15=Law (Joshua, Patricia)
Lecture 7=Philosophy (Patricia, Joshua, Mary, Joseph, Sandra)
Lecture 17=Mathematics (Jessica)
Lecture 13=German ()
```

***Note: nobody takes German, but it is still listed because professor 2 teaches German this year

I don't want to do a separate query for each lecture like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name, ' ' ORDER BY RAND() SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM students p, lectures_students q
WHERE q.lectureid = 17 
AND p.id = q.studentid
AND p.instate = 1
```

How could I achieve this nested list in one query?

I did look at solutions on various threads in the forums, but still cannot understand how to write a query for all my specifications, especially the "no student for this class" condition

Thank you very much for your help.  I'm an amateur programmer, but this is beyond my realm of competence.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want `left join`s and aggregation. You can start joining from `lectures`, and then follow the relationships to `lecture_students`, then `students`; the filter on `'inState'` students must be placed in the `on` clause of the `left join`. Then, you can aggregate by lecture and list the names of all students who attended each lecture.

```
select 
    l.id,
    l.name, 
    group_concat(s.name order by s.id) student_names
from lectures l
left join lecture_student ls on ls.professorId = l.professorId
left join student s on s.id = ls.studentId and s.inState = 1
where l.professorid = 2 and l.offeredthisyear = 1
group by l.id, l.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have quite settled on what your actual table names are (i.e. you have not been consistent), so you will have to excuse me if I don't have them quite right.

The following SQL uses the currently accepted JOIN synax:

```
SELECT l.name, GROUP_CONCAT(p.name ORDER BY s.name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM LECTURE l LEFT JOIN LECTURE_STUDENT ls on l.id = ls.professorID
LEFT JOIN STUDENT s ON ls.studentID = s.id
WHERE s.inState = 1
GROUP BY l.name
```

Note: I have used `l`, `s` and `ls` as alises for the tables in a more logical fashion.

I am using left joins on `LECTURE_STUDENT` and `STUDENT` in case there are no students enrolled in a particular lecture.

Comment: Ronald, thank you.  Sorry I have the variable / table names confused.  Please see my response below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both responders.  I've combined to get the correct result.  This code works.

```
SELECT 
    l.id,
    l.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.name ORDER BY RAND() SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM lectures l
LEFT JOIN lectures_students ls ON ls.lectureid = l.id
LEFT JOIN students s ON s.id = ls.studentId AND s.inState = 1
WHERE l.professorid = 2 AND l.offeredthisyear = 1
GROUP BY l.id, l.name
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: I was looking at the SQL you had under the caption **I don't want to do a separate query for each lecture like this:** where you did *not* have `WHERE l.professorid = 2 AND l.offeredthisyear = 1` and that is why I did not include those conditions in my SQL. It really wasn't clear what conditions you were interested in. I think the essence of your issue were the joins.